# Определить собственную функцию и передать её в стандартную функцию apply

Tags: lisp

Задание такое: в зависимости от переданного значения функции, с помощью apply выполнить либо сложение элементов списка, либо умножение элементов списка.
т.е.

```
apply func(x) '(1 2 3 4)
```

если x = 1, то результат- 10, если x = 2, то 24

вот, что сделал я:

определяю функцию func

```
(defun func_(x) (cond ((eql 1 x)(plus))(eql 2 x)(TIMES))
```

затем пытаюсь вызвать apply

```
(apply func_(1) '(1 2 3 4))
```

но компилятор выдает ошибку

> Error: The variable FUNC_ is unbound.
>   Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging
>   Error signalled by EVAL.
>   Backtrace: EVAL
>   Broken at SYSTEM::GCL-TOP-LEVEL.

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём интерпретаторе нет функций `plus` и `TIMES` (точнее, `TIMES` была уже ранее определена по-другому), однако я сразу вижу у Вас странную вещь - Вы пытаетесь вызвать `func_` не в стиле языка LISP. Попробуйте заменить Ваше

```
(apply func_(1) '(1 2 3 4))
```

на

```
(apply (func_ 1) '(1 2 3 4))
```

Также я решил переписать Вашу функцию `func_` с использованием + и *, получилось следующее:

```
(defun func_(x) (cond ((eql 1 x)(lambda (&rest ns) (apply '+ ns)))((eql 2 x)(lambda (&rest ns) (apply '* ns)))))
```